# iPhone UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown issue

Tags: iphone, animation

I added a UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp while calling a new view, which worked fine but now when I try to do the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown using the code below to call another view it doesn't work.

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to this and was wondering where I went wrong.

Thanks.

```
 ViewController *getPage = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


    getPage.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown;
    [self presentModalViewController:getPage animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIViewController's modalTransitionStyle property only supports a few different styles.  See [the reference doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

If you want to use one other than these, you can't do it via presentModalViewController.